# Connect COM1 port with socat

Tags: windows, serial-port, socat

Is it possible to connect socat to the COM1 device? I am trying to use example from socat man page `socat -,raw,echo=0,escape=0x0f /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0,crnl` and replace device name `/dev/ttyS0` with windows specific device name. I've tried `COM1`, `com1`, `com1:`, `com1\:`, some other variants but nothing works. Does anybody know correct combinations of symbols for the device name?

Answer (score 1):

Use standard Linux name convention:

- `/dev/ttyS0` is equivalent to COM1
- `/dev/ttyS1` is equivalent to COM2
- etc...

See [*POSIX devices*](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-posixdevices) in the Cygwin User's Guide